# SAPUI5 - get model header and items in the controller

Tags: binding, model, odata, sapui5

I'm working on a simple Master detail SAPUI5 app.
I use V2 Odata Model an TwoWay binding.
When I click on the submit button I want to get all the values entered by the user in the model.

The problem is that I get only header data but not items data.
I need both in order to use the create deep entity method in the backend.

Here is my code:

```js
var sPath = evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
var myData = evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject(sPath);
```

In myData I get the header data and the navigation propoerty with no data in it.

How can I get the items data as well ?

I tried with expand but no success !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it in the following way ?

```
 var sPath = evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath(),
 var myData = yourModel.getProperty(sPath);
```

If you model has a particular name you could do something like this -

```
var sPath = evt.getSource().getBindingContext("modelName").getPath(),
var myData = this.getView().getModel("modelName").getProperty(sPath);
```

You always need to get the path, and using it, you get the value in that path for the model

Comment: Yes, I have tried all these ways.
I always get the same thing: Header data with a field "Header_to_Items" but with no data in it.

Comment: And my model doesn't have a name.

Comment: So if you execute this.getView().getModel().getData() do you get anything? Can you show me the model structure ?